# Identical HTML5 video with preload="metadata" results in download of 79kb on one page, 1.4mb on another - Why?

Tags: html, performance, video, browser

I'm using GTMetrix to test, but I can get the same results with other tools like (webpagetest.org). The only differences in these two video tags is the fallback source. I have tried without the fallback though and it still does the same thing.

In both cases a 206 response code (Partial Content) it returned, but in one case it's **loading 57 times more data!** 1.4mb is the full size of the video file. Since it seems to be downloading the entire thing in one case, the 206 code is confusing.

I can't find any way to explain this discrepancy, but it's persisted for a month across browsers and testing services.

---

### [Page 1](https://recollectr.io/home-old/)

#### Preloads 79kb - [(Waterfall graph)](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/recollectr.io/MhgWeAsi#waterfall)

```html
<video muted="" id="main-demo-video" preload="metadata" width="984" height="670">
    <source src="https://recollectr.io/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Main-Demo-V3-Fullsize.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="https://recollectr.io/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Main-Demo-v3-Fullsize-x265.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

---

### [Page 2](https://recollectr.io/)

#### Preloads 1.4mb - [(Waterfall graph)](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/recollectr.io/MhgWeAsi#waterfall)

```html
<video muted="" id="main-demo-video" preload="metadata" width="984" height="670">
    <source src="https://recollectr.io/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Main-Demo-V3-Fullsize.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="https://recollectr.io/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Main-Demo-V2-Fullsize.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: is it consistent across browsers, or does the behavior change only between browsers? is the video optimized with the MOOV atom at the start of the file (to facilitate metadata loading?)

Comment: The handling isn't identical across browsers, but there is a difference in how it's loaded even in Firefox across the two pages. Page A: https://www.webpagetest.org/result/180720_10_879f3a47ee3f012c53bbce7b1eebe209/1/details/ Page B: https://www.webpagetest.org/result/180720_JY_0430d84eaeeddc8759483e5f677e18b3/1/details/ - No use of `MOOV` here. The video in question is encoded with `webm`